# URLDownloadToFile QtCreator file not downloading

Tags: c++, qt

My issue today involve the usage of `URLDownloadToFile()` with QtCreator. I use the following code to download:

```
HRESULT hRez = URLDownloadToFile(NULL, TEXT(url), TEXT("C:\\image.png"), 0, NULL);
if (hRez != S_OK)
{
    return false;
}
```

The code run with no errors however the file ins't downloaded. I've been searching through many solutions for my issue but none have been relevant not successful. What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Well [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms775123(v=vs.85).aspx) states:

```
szFileName:
  A pointer to a string value containing the name or full path of the file to create for the download. 
  If szFileName includes a path, the target directory must already exist.
```

So I would assume this parameter needs to include not only a path but a filename as well. For instance

```
HRESULT hRez = URLDownloadToFile(NULL, TEXT(url), TEXT("C:\\downl.tmp"), 0, NULL);
```

Comment: Oh! I missed writing that in the summary of the code. The exact path + filename is mentioned in the original. Edited the post...